# OpenCV Mat 'expected ")"' in method parameter

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am currently developing a Mac application which involves mixing C++ and Objective C. I am trying to separate part of the application into a cpp source file and I can't get the damn thing to compile.

Bear in mind I am *very* new to using c++ so forgive me if I have made a really stupid error.

I've managed to pare it down to the most minimal example I possibly can. For some reason when I use the `Mat` data type within a method declaration, I get

`expected ')'`

My header file

```
#ifndef MATCHTEMPLATES_H
#define MATCHTEMPLATES_H

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

class Matcher {
   public:
      Matcher(cv::Mat& template);
};
#endif
```

my source file

```
#include "Matcher.hpp"

using namespace cv;

Matcher::Matcher(Mat& template) { }
```

compile commands

`clang++ -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/include/opencv -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/include -o CMakeFiles/Tracker.dir/source/cpp/Matcher.cpp.o -c {project location}/source/cpp/Matcher.cpp`

Comment: `template` is a reserved keyword?

Comment: DOH. That would be the stupid mistake I was talking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, stupid mistake.

Apparently 'template' is a reserved word in c++

Thanks Sebastian Hoffman for pointing that out...